# find the node with minimum value in a binary search tree (print that node)

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I have to find the node with the minimum value in a binary search tree.I wrote the function but I can't display the node with the minimum value.This is the tree

```
struct Node
{
    int key; 
    void *info; 
    Node *left, *right;
};
```

and this is the function

```
Node* findMin(Node* r)
{
    if (r == 0)
        return 0;
    else if (r->left == 0)
        return r;
    else
        return findMin(r->left);
}
```

I call the function like this in main file:

```
Node *root = makeTree(); // I enter the values and insert them into a binary search tree with an insert function.
root = findMin(root);
cout << root;
```

It displays the adress and not the value.What should I make to display the node with the minimum value?

Comment: You are getting the address of `node` but you are looking for the value of the member `info`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access

Comment: FYI -- To find the minimum value, keep going `left` on the BST until you get to the leaf.  You don't need any of the recursion, just a plain iterative loop.

Answer (score 0):

In this statement

```
root = findMin(root);
```

you are overwriting the pointer to the root node of the tree.

The function can look the following way

```
Node * findMin( Node *node )
{
    return node == nullptr || node->left == nullptr ? node : findMin( node->left );
}
```

To display the found value write

```
auto node = findMin( root );

if ( node ) std::cout << node->key << '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int minValue(struct node* node)  
{  
    struct node* current = node;  

    /* loop down to find the leftmost leaf */
    while (current->left != NULL)  
    {  
        current = current->left;  
    }  
    return(current->data);  
}
```

Comment: This fails on `node == NULL`. The problem statement does not clearly state the tree is non-empty, so the `NULL` should be handled.

Comment: @anuj-padmawar Thank you for answering this question, but please consider not only providing the correct code, but also explaining what the OP did wrong and how you corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

> It displays the adress and not the value.What should I make to display the node with the minimum value?

It is because you need to dereference the pointer to display the value. Inside your main function:

```
Node *root = makeTree();
root = findMin(root);
if (root)
    cout << root->key;
else
    cout << "Tree empty\n";
```